# R session is aborted using random forest of "caret" package

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, r-caret

The table has `560,304` rows, and `10` columns. I used the `caret package random Forest` to train my model. Before training, I defined my columns time and classification types. other columns do not need direct type defining.  I used `rose` sampling because of the data imbalanced classification. I did not use the first column because it is the identifier. Here is my code:

```
require(openxlsx)
library(chron)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)

set.seed(9560)
record<-read.xlsx('_3.xlsx',sheet =1 , colNames = TRUE,
                  rowNames = FALSE, skipEmptyRows = TRUE)

#Define column types
record$TIME <- chron(times=record$TIME)
record$Is.Fraud <- factor(record$Is.Fraud)


MyControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedCV", repeats=5, 
                          sampling="rose")
#train model 
rfModel <- train(record$Is.Fraud ~.,data=record[,2:10],method='rf',
                 trControl=MyControl)
```

However, the `R session` is aborted and crashed.

when I `upsample` data and use two different random Forest and combine them there is no problem even when I use `upsampling` instead of `rose`. the following code works fine:

```
upSmp<-upSample(x = record[, 2:9],y=record$Is.Fraud)
upSmp <- upSmp[sample(nrow(upSmp)),]
rdFrst1<-randomForest(Class ~.,data=upSmp[1:(nrow(upSmp)/2),])
rdFrst2<-randomForest(Class ~.,data=upSmp[((nrow(upSmp)/2)+1):nrow(upSmp),])
rf.combined <- combine(rdFrst1,rdFrst2)
```

I think there is a problem with my memory when I use `repeatedcv`. What is my problem? Can I handle it in `caret` train function with combining two random forest like how I used `RandomForest` function and combined models?

I attached the step it is stoped in [image: here].

Comment: Have you monitored memory usage while running the function? Is the crash immediate after you run the code or after a while?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik it is after a while. no I have not monitor. I have 16 GB RAM there should not be any problem !

Comment: My suggestion would be to monitor memory usage and see if anything funny happens. Running out of memory is probably not very likely, because SWAP would be used which means your computer would grind to a practical halt. You could try and start adding more and more data to see where the breaking point is and if this happens randomly or perhaps is caused by specific line(s) of data.

Comment: Is there a typo in your above code ? You wrote `data=record[2:10]` so if record is a dataframe or a matrix you are not selecting the columns 2 to 10, a comma is missing, shouldn't it be : `data=record[,2:10]` ?

Comment: @PierreChevallier that was typo. I attached the picture when it got stock. it cannot resample.

Comment: How many rows foes `upSmp` have?

Comment: @DooshizePlusPlus Are you using RStudio ? There might be something to look into regarding data management and handling, since `data.frame` is a very hefty class and if the data are stored as `double` the memory can quickly be overflowed in RStudio and abort the session from time to time.